# Decomposing a number into powers of 2

Tags: swift, for-loop, bit-manipulation

Hi I need to decompose a number into powers of 2 in swift 5 for an iOS app I'm writing fro a click and collect system.

The backend of this system is written in c# and uses the following to save a multi-pick list of options as a single number in the database eg:

choosing salads for a filled roll on an order system works thus:

```
lettuce = 1
cucumber = 2
tomato = 4
sweetcorn = 8
onion = 16
```

by using this method it saves the options into the database for the choice made as (lettuce + tomato + onion) = 21 (1+4+16)

at the other end I use a c# function to do this thus:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
    {
    int mask = 1 << j;
    }
```

I need to convert this function into a swift 5 format to integrate the decoder into my iOS app

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I this a bit flag enum in C#? One annotated with `[Flags]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I figured it out this is my final solution:

```
    var salads = "" as String
    let value = 127
    var j=0
    while j < 256 {

        let mask=1 << j
        if((value & mask) != 0) {
            salads.append(String(mask) + ",")
        }
        j += 1
    }
    salads = String(salads.dropLast()) // removes the final ","
    print(salads)
```

This now feeds nicely into the in clause in my SQL query, thanks you all for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, these bit fields are expressed as option sets, which are types that conform to the [`OptionSet` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset). Here is an example for your use case:

```
struct Veggies: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: UInt32

    static let lettuce = Veggies(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let cucumber = Veggies(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let tomato = Veggies(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let sweetcorn = Veggies(rawValue: 1 << 3)
    static let onion = Veggies(rawValue: 1 << 4)
}

let someVeggies: Veggies = [.lettuce, .tomato]
print(someVeggies) // => Veggies(rawValue: 5)

print(Veggies.onion.rawValue) // => 16
```

OptionSets are better than just using their raw values, for two reasons:

1) They standardize the names of the cases, and gives a consistent and easy way to interact with these values
2) `OptionSet` derives from the `SetAlgebra` protocol, and provides defaulted implementations for many useful methods like `union`, `intersection`, `subtract`, `contains`, etc.

I would caution against this design, however. Option sets are useful only when there's a really small number of flags (less than 64), that you can't forsee expanding. They're really basic, can't store any payload besides "x exists, or it doesn't", and they're primarily intended for use cases that have very high sensitivity for performance and memory use, which quick rare these days. I would recommend using regular objects (Veggie class, storing a name, and any other relevant data) instead.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for your reply, I am handling an integer here that has been parsed from a rest API from a mysql database using Json from this number I need to break it down into the power 2 components i.e - 21 goes into this function and it needs to spit out a string (1,4,16) so I can then do another Json call to retrieve these name values.

this may not be pretty but it is the hand I have been dealt! :)

what would be the most elegant way of doing this?

(this is my first ever question on stack overflow please forgive my inaptitude)

Comment: @Drewby80 Yep, option sets fit that bill perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a while loop, like this :

```
var j = 0
while j < 32 {
    var mask = 1 << j
    j += 1
}
```

[Here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html) is a link about loops and control flow in Swift 5.

Comment: Or use a for loop. `for j in 0..<32 {`